# How to read contents of a directory recursively in Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I want to implement a tree traversal function which prints all the contents of  a given directory 
in kernel . I know how to do this in user space, but my requirement is to have that in kernel space.
For that, I am looking into vfs_readdir function and a bit confused regarding its usage.
Say I will be calling my traversal function from other kernel module which means that request won’t be coming through user space. Now the question is how to call vfs_readdir and use that information to recursively parse given directory. From definition of vfs_readdir
extern int vfs_readdir(struct file *, filldir_t, void *);

I can get struct file * from the file path using functions like filp_open() and as per my understanding filldir_t is a function pointer to call back function which fills the user provided buffer pointed by void *. But in my case, I don’t need to pass any information to user back. What should i pass in void * place?
Looking into filldir function definition

static int filldir(void * __buf, const char * name, int namlen, loff_t offset, ino_t ino, unsigned int d_type);

From where are the parameters to this function are coming. My assumption is that vfs_readdir in turn calls something like file->f_op_readdir(file,but,filler);
Does this internally does something and fills in parameters to call callback function ?
Now this is one level. What should I do to recursively print all files in a given directory. I guess I need to do something in my own callback function.But I have only some information regarding the file that are passed through this call back functions like name of file,inode number etc . How would I know if it is regular file or directory using this information . I mean I don't have dentry or inode data structures regarding the file. Any suggestions how to do that?
In addition, If I want to delete a file in callback function, can I do that by using inode numbers(thats what i have in callback apart from names) how should I do that?

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Exchange network! You should upvote helpful answers to your - or any - questions. The best answers should be accepted to give the answerers the credit and to inform others that your issue is resolved. See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 5):

`vfs_readdir` is called, e.g., from [readdir syscall implementation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/readdir.c?v=3.10#L105). It uses `fillonedir` as callback, which in turn can easy be understanded: its first argument is just last argument of `vfs_readdir`, all other arguments(`name`, `namelen`, `offset`, `ino`, `d_type`) are copied into user space as is.

Note, that callback for `vfs_readdir` is executed with inode mutex locked(`inode->i_mutex`). Probably you shoudn't open subdirectory incide that callback. Instead, save name of the subdirectory somewhere, and open it *after* `vfs_readdir` call. This is very similar to the way how you traverse directories tree in the user space.

Note, that since version 3.11 kernel uses another way for iterate entries in directory: `iterate_dir`. Its second argument combines both callback and callback-specific argument for it, and also include current position in the file. Aside from the first parameter, callback accepts same parameters as before.

As for `ino` argument, you cannot use it for open given inode(kernel just has no mechanism for *open* files by inode number). Use `filp_open` or similar.

Comment: If I am not going to open subdirectory in callback . how should I go by deciding whether file is directory or not(if it is subdirectory i may save it) without opening it as merely have a name of a file

Comment: You can use `d_type` for determine entry type. BTW, you do the same in the user space, don't it?