# How to read a directory in kernel space?

Tags: linux-kernel, directory, fs

It could be done using opendir and readdir in user space. But, how to process in kernel space? I just know the mainly function is vfs_readdir or iterate_dir, but who could show me the total stage with a sample code. Any answer will be thankful.

Comment: Isn't there anything helpful in the kernel source tree? [iterate_dir](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=iterate_dir) , [vfs_readdir](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=3.10;i=vfs_readdir) ...

Comment: See also that similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617244/how-to-read-contents-of-a-directory-recursively-in-linux-kernel).

Comment: I have reviewed the kernel source about  iterate_dir and vfs_readdir. I just don`t know how to use those function.